# Как работать с диапазоном дат

Tags: c#

Есть класс `Person`. Он водитель. График его работы 2 через 2. Допустим его взяли на работу сегодня и сегодня же он приступил к работе. (03.06.2018). Как узнать когда начинается смена этого `Person` в определенную дату. Допусти через 35 дней?

Comment: Прибавить к дате 35 дней?

Comment: @tym32167 ну допустим прибавим.  А дальше как узнать когда его смена?

Comment: Что значит когда? Имеется ввиду рабочий или нет сегодня у него день? Что у Вас вызывает затруднение? У Вас вопрос типа решите за меня - это тут не приветствуется.

Comment: @Dejsving все верно. Рабочий день у него или нет. Я не прошу решить задачу заменя, подкиньте алгоритм. Мозг не может осилить эту математику

Comment: `((start + count) / 2) % 2 == 0` если модуль от 2х начала и необходимой даты поделенный на 2 равен нулю то рабочий день, если нет то выходной.

Comment: что такое count?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант могу предложить следующую идею:

Работаем с кол-вом отработанных дней.

Так как работа 2 через 2, то цикл работы/отдыха 4 дня,
берем кол-во отработанных дней и вычисляем остаток от деления на 4.

Рабочие дни это остаток 1 и 2. А выходные - это 3 и 0.

Для вычисления этого самого кол-ва храним дату первого рабочего дня и вычисляем разность текущей даты и даты первого рабочего дня.

Comment: А если график 1/3?

Comment: @Zevra: Как это относится к вашему вопросу, там явно указано 2/2?

Comment: @Yami я так) на будущее

Comment: @Dejsving алгоритм не совсем корректный,

Comment: @Yami ???????????????

Comment: Я написал - как вариант - это идея с бухты барахты - предложите свою, если вам мой вариант не нравится

Comment: @Zevra, идея не может быть корректной или не корректной. Реализация имеет параметр Корректность, а не идея.